# Selenium Webdriver Findsby VB syntax

Tags: c#, vb.net, selenium-webdriver

I have the c# syntax for finding an id:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "email")]
private IWebElement emailAddressTextField;
```

But what is the VB.NET equivalent? There is not much information with Selenium and VB...

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this to convert the code:

http://converter.telerik.com/

```
<FindsBy(How := How.Id, [Using] := "email")> _
Private emailAddressTextField As IWebElement
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks - The code is valid. But it doesn't seem to initialize to a value, it just creates a blank variable called emailAddressTextField.

Comment: You may be misunderstanding how the `PageFactory` implementation works, @levis84. The variable in your class will not be populated with an actual `IWebElement` or equivalent until that member variable is accessed at run time.

Comment: @JimEvans thanks. No, it doesn't get populated at all, I get 'object not set to an instance of an object' when I try to use the variable. I am comparing a C# example (which works) and don't see the difference:

'code' [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "email")]
'code' private IWebElement emailAddressTextField;

'code' emailAddressTextField.SendKeys(EmailAdd);

Comment: @levis84, you do have to call `PageFactory.InitElements` before attempting to access the variable, and you've not indicated that you've done so.

Comment: Thanks - think I understand it now. I need to start again with my framework though. Cheers!